# USB Device Controller Driver Specification

Tags: usb, device-driver, peripherals

For USB Host Controllers there are the UHCI/OHCI/EHCI/XHCI specification that define how to program a driver. Is there an equivalent specification for USB Device Controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Generally, every USB-capable microcontroller has a USB block that you can control by writing to some registers in your code, but those registers are pretty different on the different microcontrollers and I have not heard of any attempt to standardize them.